ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mmdet.models.utils.res_layer'
==> Use enhancement and guidance module !
Loading text detection model from "models/dbnet++.pth" as our guided net!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 144, in <module>
    run_train(opt, device, train_adv_path, train_per_path, Generator_path, loss_path)
  File "/home/qz/zyc/workspace/c/AI_Code/ProTegO-main/train_protego.py", line 43, in run_train
    ProTegO.train(train_dataloader, opt.epochs, train_adv_path, train_per_path, Generator_path, loss_path)
  File "/home/qz/zyc/workspace/c/AI_Code/ProTegO-main/protego.py", line 192, in train
    gui_net = torch.load(self.dt_model).to(self.device)
  File "/home/qz/miniconda3/envs/protego/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 789, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/home/qz/miniconda3/envs/protego/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1131, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "/home/qz/miniconda3/envs/protego/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1124, in find_class
    return super().find_class(mod_name, name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mmdet.models.utils.res_layer'

I want to run the code

Hey Syclus, the question lacks context to be answerable. Could you describe how you installed mmdet and a minimal example that raises the code. Probably only an import statement.

Thank you, I have resolved the issue. It should be due to incompatible versions of the mmcv library and mmdet library
